# Calculating Enhanced Vegetation Index (EVI) using Sentinel-2 Level 1C, value problem

Tags: remote-sensing, sentinel-2, evi

I am trying to calculate EVI values from Sentinel-2 Level 1C. When I calculate the EVI with this formula : **(2.5 * ("Band 8" - "Band 4")) / ("Band 8" + (2.4 * "Band 4") + 1)** I got values between -79.6462 to 22.6748. I used to know that EVI ranges between -1 to +1.

I tried [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/247330) to [Calculating 2-bands EVI from Sentinel-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/226325/115), but I still have problems.

When I changed the formula as **(2.5 * float("Band 8"/10000 - "Band 4"/10000)) / ("Band 8"/10000 + (2.4 * "Band 4"/10000) + 10000)** my values are between -0.000169 to 0.0003. These are close but not expected values too.

Now I want to know if my procedure is okay and what the correct use of the formula for Level 1C is?

Comment: Correct formula is as follows: 2.5 * float("Band 8"/10000 - "Band 4"/10000)) / ("Band 8"/10000 + (2.4 * "Band 4"/10000) + 1)

Comment: What software are you using to do that?

Comment: I am using python, in script I try this :  
evi = 2.5*(nir.astype(float)-red.astype(float))/((nir.astype(float)+(6.0*red.astype(float))+(-7.5*blue.astype(float))+1.0))
and the result is between -79.6462 to 22.6748. I divided all band values with 10000 before this line. Is it related with python? parentheses or something?

Answer (score 1):

Just as xunilk said, you shoud replace that last 10000 with 1.
The correct formula is:
EVI = 2.5 * ("Band 8"/10000 - "Band 4"/10000) / ("Band 8"/10000 + 2.4*"Band 4"/10000 + 1)

I just tested it with a sentinel image and the results was between -0.6 and 1.5 which seems to be acceptable.

Comment: At first I divided all bands with 10000, when I said that **2.5 * ("Band 8" - "Band 4")) / ("Band 8" + (2.4 * "Band 4") + 1) I got values between -79.6462 to 22.6748. **  The result is not expected.

Comment: which image did you use for this? which level image? @Parsa

Comment: I don't remember the image level. But my image values were between 1 and 28000. What is range of your original image values?

Comment: It depends on bands, 
in B02 band : 646 to 3172
in B04 band : 289 to 4103
in B08 band : 181 to 5575

Comment: I just realized that you didn't use the blue band in calculations. I remember that your formula is for evi2 calculation.